# how to force user-apps to resolve "route lookup" using specfic routing table

Tags: linux, network-programming

I understand that 
a. one can maintain multiple routing tables in linux using "ip route ..... table "
b. forwarding decision for packets that ingress from outside network could be done using "ip rule add iif dev  table "

However, if I want an user-app to talk to the outside world using specific routing table, I don't see an easy way out except to use "ip netns".

Is there a way to tell the system to use "lookup route" using specific routing table?

My understanding is "ip rules" apply only after a packet has been generated, but the user-apps consult the routing table even before the packet is generated so that ARP for the gateway can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated matter. You should familiarize with SELinux labels and containers.
Docker documentation for RedHat states:

> by default, docker creates a virtual ethernet card for each container. each container has its own routing tables and iptables. in addition to this, when you ask for specific ports to be forwarded, docker creates certain host iptables rules for you. the docker daemon itself does some of the proxying. the takeaway here is that if you map applications to containers, you provide flexibility to yourself by limiting network access on a per-application basis.

Comment: Thanks. But am trying to do this without going for container.  As I understand container uses namespaces and this implies the network device visibility is also partitioned.